# Error in Yii dropdown add link option

Tags: ajax, yii

I am newbie to the beautifull Yii Framework.I was going through the wiki docs of Yii.I got a link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/72/cjuidialog-and-ajaxsubmitbutton? where I got something that I was needed.So I made all the process like the tutorial.But still I am not able to save the job_name from the person view file.

My database was like this

```
 ==== Job ====
  id
  job_name
  job_description
  created_at
  updated_at

  ==== Person ====
  id
  job_id
  person_name
  description
  created_at
  updated_at
```

My _form.php for Person was like this

```
 <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
  <div class="row">
  <div id="job">
  <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'job_id',CHtml::listData(Job::model()->findAll(),'job_id','description'),array('prompt'=>'Select')); ?>
  <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(Yii::t('job','Create Job'),$this->createUrl('job/addnew'),array(
  'onclick'=>'$("#jobDialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
  'update'=>'#jobDialog'
  ),array('id'=>'showJobDialog'));?>
  <div id="jobDialog"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

And the actionAddnew() in job controller is like this

```
public function actionAddnew()
  {
    $model=new Job;
    // Ajax Validation enabled
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    // Flag to know if we will render the form or try to add 
    // new jon.
    $flag=true;
    if(isset($_POST['Job']))
    {
      $flag=false;
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Job'];
      if($model->save()) 
      {
        //Return an <option> and select it
        echo CHtml::tag('option',array ('value'=>$model->jid,'selected'=>true),CHtml::encode($model->jdescr),true);
      }
     }
      if($flag) 
      {
        Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
        $this->renderPartial('createDialog',array('model'=>$model,),false,true);
      }
  }
```

As per the tutorial I have made another two files called as createDialog.php and _formDialog.php in job view folder.
  The code for createDialog.php is like this

```
<?php 
  $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
  'id'=>'jobDialog',
  'options'=>array(
  'title'=>Yii::t('job','Create Job'),
  'autoOpen'=>true,
  'modal'=>'true',
  'width'=>'auto',
  'height'=>'auto',
  ),
  ));
  echo $this->renderPartial('_formDialog', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
  <?php $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');?>
```

The code for _formDialog.php is like this

```
 <div class="form" id="jobDialogForm">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'job-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); 
//I have enableAjaxValidation set to true so i can validate on the fly the
?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'jid'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'jid',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>90)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'jid'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'jdescr'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'jdescr',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>180)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'jdescr'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(Yii::t('job','Create Job'),CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('job/addnew','render'=>false)),array('success'=>'js: function(data) {
                        $("#Person_jid").append(data);
                        $("#jobDialog").dialog("close");
                    }'),array('id'=>'closeJobDialog')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

So where I am wrong in this?Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Your question is so terribly broad that it cannot be answered. What does "not getting any success" mean? Be more specific. *Way* more specific.

Comment: I have updated the question.By the way I want to save the job name from the person model view file with the ajax link which has been described above the link.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `Job` model:

```
public function rules() {
  return array(
    ...
    array('job_name', 'safe'),
    ...
  );
}
```